# Plugin help files not found

Tags: plugin-system, help-system

I am on windows 10 and installed pathogen into home/vimfiles/autoload, and as far as I know all went well. Following the directions [here](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter), I installed nerdcommenter. I restarted gvim, tried :help nerdcommenter, and got E109 Sorry no help for nerdcommenter.

Can someone suggest a next step?

EDIT: the plugin itself did install (as shown in the gvim plugin menu); the issue is that the help files somehow are not associated or connected properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you have to create the help-tags.
Run `:helptags` for the dir where you installed the docs.

On unix this would most likely be `:helptags ~/.vim/doc`.

Or simply recreate them all with `:helptags ALL`